# process JSON data with AJAX

Tags: ajax, json

My aim is to display the content of my JSON data which I receive from my PHP file.

PHP is sending :

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

AJAX--->
ajax is receiving "data" and displaying : data = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

for example, item "c" to get "3". How can is display  the something like :

alert(' a = "+..--->what must i put here<-----.);

I tried : date[2], but it is not working ! is says : UNDEFINED
------->

solution :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert( obj.a);
```

thx to all for you help !

Comment: i believe it's would be date[b] to display 2 the first object is the key : and the second is the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to parse JSON in ajax or javascript

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');

alert( obj.name === "John" );

Comment: hmmm...so if data={"name":"John"} , i just need to set :var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('data'); !?!? i will try

Comment: ------->

solution :

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

alert( obj.a);


thx to all for you help !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`data["c"]`

That should work.